# Custom model binder for abstract child objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding

I have a concrete view model which has members which are abstract classes.

I have a custom model binder which detects abstract classes and uses a hidden field to determine type. This seems to work ok except that the model binder doesn't seem to bind for the abstract children objects so they are always null.

How do I make my model binder behave recursively over the whole object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my child members were not Properties and so weren't public to the binder.

The solution is to make the members properties and then they are crawled by the binder as expected.